# How do I check if there are duplicates in a list? If so, how can I check how many duplicates there are?

Tags: python

I have a line of code that makes a list from a to z

```
possible_draws = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
```

and a user randomly draws 6 letters from inside (Can dupe)

People say that sample doesn't dupe, what should I do then?

```
user_numbers = random.sample(possible_draws, 6)
```

Then I print User_numbers

```
print(user_numbers)
```

To show the player what letters have been drawn.

But I don't know how to check if there are duplicates in

```
user_numbers
```

and if there are duplicates, how many duplicates are there?

*If there is more than 1 duplicate set, it would pick the one with more duplicates.

How could I do that?

Comment: `sample` doesn't dupe.

Comment: You could use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) if there were dupes, which as @KellyBundy points out there won't be...

Comment: *"People say that sample doesn't dupe, what should I do then?"* - Nothing?

Answer (score 0):

```
user_numbers = ...  #Insert your list here


list3 = []
list3a = {}
for i in user_numbers:
    if i not in list3:
        list3.append(i)
    else:
        if i not in list3a:
            list3a[i] = 1
        else:
            list3a[i] += 1
```

I just used list3 & list3a here as they were handy in my IDE when double checking myself. It'll output a list with duplicates removed (list3) and the number of duplicates(not including original) in a dictionary in list3a

list3a can be sorted quite easily as per:

```
list3b = dict(sorted(list3a.items(), key=lambda item: item[1],reverse=True),)
```

and if your using Python 3.7+, then the highest repetitive number is given by:

```
next(iter(list3b))
```

Comment: `list3b` is a strange name for a `dict`...

Comment: ha! It is all right. Firing it together with scant regard for legibility or standards!! :-D